# Processing files in C under different operating systems

Tags: c, file, text, operating-system, format

I am working with files in C. They are very, very huge files.
I read and write to these files (they are just formatted text files).
I give no extension to them;
I just say `fopen("filename","r")`.

Now a file has contents like

```
1 line1 100
2 line2 200
.
.
20000 line 20000 14567
```

The problem is I am executing it in Mac OS (Leopard to be particular) and when I open the same file (no extension) in another o/s (Windows to be particular) the program fails to read the contents of the file.
I suppose it's because the formatting of the file is differing.

Any solutions for a standard file format or extension that does not conflict with other o/s?

Comment: Just because the file have no extensions, the are not un-openable in Windows. Do you get an error opening them? Reading them? What error in that case (check `errno`)? Also, when copying the file from OSX to Windows, did you copy them in a way so you get correct line endings (they differ on OSX and Windows)?

Comment: The format of text formats differ very little between operating systems. Could you be more specific about how you are "opening" the file on both OS? Do you by calls to `fopen` in your program or by double-clicking the file?

Comment: Consider opening the file with `fopen("a", "rb");` on both systems.  On Windows, you won't get the normal CRLF to LF mapping (because there are no CRLF line endings to map), but you will be able to read the file.  This lack of mapping would matter if you use `fgets()` or similar line-oriented functions; it doesn't matter if you use `getc()` or other byte-oriented functions.

Comment: 1.Nope i dont get any error while opening.2.the files are directly created by the program .3 yes i open with fopen() 3. i used fscanf , to read the above formatted content. At some point in my program i will generate a file and then the program consumes this and proceeds to generate another set of files and they are consumed elsewhere , in OSX all the files are made and consumed properly but in windows a file is made but due to some unknown behaviour the program doesnot read the expected format and generates empty files (useless)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with plaintext files, remember that in Unix and Unix-like OSes lines end with `\n` and in Windows they end with `\r\n`.

If you do a file transfer as plaintext between operating systems, your client may change the line endings to be compatible with your target OS. You can set the transfer to binary so that you get an exact byte representation of the original file.

Comment: I often produce plain text files on Linux and send them to colleagues who work with them on Windows and still never any problem has raised.

Comment: The program creates few files (formatted like the example ive mentioned in the question) but surprisingly it works on leopard and same genrated files dont on windows, i am not writing any particular format to my files, its just simple characters!